# Domain index in materialized view return zero rows

Tags: oracle, indexing, materialized-views

I have problem with Oracle DB - domain index returns zero rows after search by CONTAINS() on materialized view. I see that materialized view is filled with data and I also used procedure ctx_ddl.sync_index() for domain index synchronization.

**What works good:**

- CREATE TABLE
- INSERT DATA
- CREATE DOMAIN INDEX
- SYNC DOMAIN INDEX
- FIND ROWS BY CONTAINS - RETURN ROWS

**What is not working:**

- CREATE TABLE
- INSERT DATA
- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
- REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
- CREATE DOMAIN INDEX IN MATERIALIZED VIEW
- SYNC DOMAIN INDEX IN MATERIALIZED VIEW
- FIND ROWS BY CONTAINS IN MATERIALIZED VIEW - **RETURN ZERO ROWS** (LIKE %TERM% WORKS)

Why everything works fine without materialized view?
Here is my queries (you can copy-paste and try it in your oracle db):

`--create table
CREATE TABLE "PCOUNTERPARTY" ( "ID_COUNTERPARTY" NUMBER(10,0), "TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME" NVARCHAR2(260), CONSTRAINT "PCOUNTERPARTY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_COUNTERPARTY"));`

--INSERT DATA.
Insert into PCOUNTERPARTY (ID_COUNTERPARTY,TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME) values (1184,'MARTINKO3');

--create materialized view
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW m_pcounterparty
AS
SELECT c.ID_COUNTERPARTY, CAST( c.TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME AS varchar2(260 CHAR) ) as txt_search_full_name_all
FROM PCOUNTERPARTY c;

--create domain index
create index IDXM_1_pcounterparty on m_pcounterparty(TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME_ALL) indextype is ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)');

--refresh of materialized view
EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('M_PCOUNTERPARTY');
--refresh of index
exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('IDXM_1_pcounterparty');

--search in materialized view
SELECT
    TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME_ALL
from
   M_PCOUNTERPARTY c
WHERE
   CONTAINS(c.TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME_ALL, 'martin', 1) > 0; **--return ZERO and THIS IS PROBLEM**
   *--c.TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME_ALL LIKE '%MARTIN%';* **-- return rows but we want search thru CONTAINS**

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Text indexes normally search words, not strings.

A wildcard is not necessary to search for "martin" in "Martin Luther King Jr."  But a wildcard *is* necessary to search for "martin" in "MARTINKO3".

Change the `CONTAINS` predicate to this:

```
CONTAINS(c.TXT_SEARCH_FULL_NAME_ALL, 'martin%', 1) > 0;
```

I ran tests on Oracle 12.2 and could not find any differences in behavior between using a table or a materialized view.  Perhaps there was a test mistake or a very specific bug that caused the text indexes to act differently on your system.